# How do I style my json data on screen in form of table?

Tags: css, ios, json, reactjs, react-native

I have a screen where my data is displayed. I want to display in the form of table (The data at the bottom of screen)as shown below in screenshot.

Edited: top part code:

It's inside the movies as well

```
<View>
<Text key={item.symbol}>{item.symbol}<Text>
<Text key={item.open}>{item.open}<Text>
<Text key={item.close}>{item.close}<Text>

</View>
```

Right now my screen looks like:

[image: myscreen]

I want to create an interface like below:

[image]

The data next to the close, high etc is some json data that I fetched from api.

My Code as of now :

```
let movie = ( 
  <View  style={styles.bottomdata}>
   <Text style={styles.text} key={item.name}>
      {item.name}
    </Text>
     <Text style={styles.text} key={item.open}>
      OPEN {item.open}
    </Text>
     <Text style={styles.text} key={item.close}>
      CLOSE{item.close}
    </Text>
   <Text style={styles.text} key={item.volumes}>
      VOLUME{item.volumes}
    </Text>
     <Text style={styles.text} key={item.low}>
     LOW {item.low}
    </Text>

    <Text style={styles.text} key={item.high}>
      HIGH{item.high}
    </Text>  
  </View>
)


  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss}>
      <View style={styles.container}>
       <View>{movie}</View>   
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

   );
}



const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: "black",
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  bottomdata:
  {
      marginTop:400,
      backgroundColor:"black",
  }
});
```

The `movie` is the data displayed on the screen. How do I design it like that? And, at the top it is just the symbol name (same as at the bottom) and close and high values. How can I design my screen like that? I am able to fetch the data but not sure how to design it like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use layout the contents using a views and test which would create something like a table. The below code shows how to position items in a row.

JSX

```
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View
    style={{
      flexDirection: 'row',
      backgroundColor: 'black',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }}>
    <Text style={{ flex: 0.5, color: 'white' }}>{item.symbol}</Text>
    <Text style={{ flex: 0.5, color: 'white' }} key={item.open}>{item.open}</Text>
    <Text
      style={{
        flex: 0.5,
        color: 'white',
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        marginVertical: 5,
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        borderRadius: 10,
      }}
      key={item.close}>
      {item.close}
    </Text>
  </View>

  <View style={styles.bottomdata}>
    <Text style={[styles.text, { alignSelf: 'center' }]} key={item.name}>
      {item.name}
    </Text>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.rowItem}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>OPEN</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.open} </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rowItem}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>CLOSE</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.close}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.row}>
      <View style={styles.rowItem}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>LOW</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.low} </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.rowItem}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>HIGH</Text>
        <Text style={styles.text}>{item.high}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.rowItem}>
      <Text style={styles.text}>VOLUME</Text>
      <Text style={styles.text}>{item.volumes}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</View>
```

Styles

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'white',
  },
  bottomdata: {
    marginTop: 'auto',
    backgroundColor: 'black',
  },
  row: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    width: '100%',
  },
  rowItem: {
    width: '50%',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    paddingHorizontal: 5,
  },
});
```

Comment: It works but how can I add lines as well as its in the screenshot?

Comment: Also, how can I add the json data at the top as well? Like in the screenshot where it says symbol, close, open data with red and green background

Comment: You will have to add    borderWidth:1,
    borderColor:'white' to the rowItem style

Comment: Can you see now? The link I posted?

Comment: I mean , your question only has the bottom part code

Comment: Also, there is no code for top section as I didn't write it yet, but it would be the same code as what I already have except it would be at the top

Comment: I can add that. Give me a moment please

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215655/discussion-between-guruparan-giritharan-and-ikea).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make divs with some alignments and all and just get those data in the relavant field